# Controls contained in a Popup cannot receive mouse clicks when Popup is contained in a UserControl

Tags: wpf

I have a `UserControl` which follows the format:

```
<UserControl x:Class="apparition2.Tabs.Scene.SceneMultiPicker"
             x:Name="control"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mwt="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:apparition2.Tabs.Scene">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock x:Name="PART_SelectedItems" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <Button x:Name="PART_Button" Grid.Column="1" Width="20" Click="PART_Button_Click" />

        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" Width="200" Height="200" AllowsTransparency="True"
               PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}"
               HorizontalOffset="5" VerticalOffset="5" Placement="Left" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_Button}">
            <mwt:SystemDropShadowChrome Color="#71000000" Margin="0,0,5,5">
                <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" Padding="5">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,5" />

                        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                      Grid.Row="1">
                            <ItemsControl x:Name="PART_Items" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=control, Path=Items}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox Margin="5,3" Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay} />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </mwt:SystemDropShadowChrome>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

`PART_Button`'s Click handler sets `PART_Popup.IsOpen` to `True`. The `ItemsControl` in `PART_Popup` displays many rows of checkboxes. However, the `TextBox` and `CheckBoxs` contained within `PART_Popup` cannot receive focus.

The WPF default theme gives mouseover feedback for these controls- the `TextBox`'s border lights up and the `CheckBox` surface glows. But clicking on them do nothing. The bindings have been isolated as not affecting by replacing `PART_Popup`'s content with a simple `<Button>`. This too receives mouseover feedback but can't be clicked.

If this identical template is placed inline to the `<Window>` instead of in a `UserControl`, it works fine. What gives?

Comment: If it's any clue at all, there's even more strange behaviour. When the Popup is contained in the UserControl, mouse clicks clear the popup visibility erratically. I can click the same place in the popup nine times then have the tenth click disappear the popup. This doesn't happen when the popup is inlined.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue, very frustrating...

Answer (score 2):

To make child controls, such as TextBoxes and CheckBoxes, contained within Popup receive focus try to set `Focusable="False"` in Visual Tree parent elements.